# C# MVC: Search Grid as Partial View to enable AJAX Return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid that contains Contacts. It automatically shows contacts when people go to the /contacts/ URL. In a separate box, people can filter those by different criteria. I want to refresh only the grid, not the entire page, whenever different criteria are applied.

In order to achieve this, would I put the Contacts Grid by itself in a partial view, and somehow return the partial view via AJAX later?

Please give me a hint in the right direction. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward method is probably to use the [jQuery AJAX API](http://docs.jquery.com/AJAx) to request the method. You then use the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` property in your controller to see if the request was made with AJAX - if so, you return only the `PartialView` from the Controller action.

---

Some code examples:

In your view, you could have the following markup:

```
<div id="gridContainer">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("ContactsGrid", ViewData.Model); %>
</div>
```

(assuming your contacts are contained in the `Model` object, and the view is strongly typed...)
You then have the following javascript code called when you want to update the grid:

```
$('#gridContainer').load('/contacts/', { filterParameter: andItsValue });
```

You could also append the filter parameter in the URL, if your routes support that.

In your controller action, you do the following check before returning:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
    return PartialView("ContactsGrid", contacts);
}
return View(contacts);
```

Comment: So I should have the grid in a partial view?

Comment: Yes, the grid goes in the partial view.

Comment: In these examples, the partial view is called "ContactsGrid.ascx", btw.

Answer (score 2):

[Something I put together a while ago...](http://jarrettatwork.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-mvc-ajax-brief-introduction.html)

I think this will get you started in the right direction. It's a simple search people form using AJAX and a UserControl.